# click the button after you select the item you can be available to eat but i dont know how to doing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so basically I want to click the button after you select the item you can be available to eat,
but the problem is I don't understand how to add this to my inventory script and I am a little bit confused and need help with this.

```
inventory code 

    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
        public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
        {
          public SCInventory playerInventory;
          public PlayerActions playerAction;
          InventoryUIController InventoryUI;
          Player player;
        
          bool isSwapping;
          int tempIndex;
          Slot tempslot;
        
          
          public void currentItem(int index){
            if(playerInventory.inventorySlots[index].item){
              playerAction.SetItem(playerInventory.inventorySlots[index].item.itemPrefab);
            }
          }
          private void Start() {
             InventoryUI = gameObject.GetComponent<InventoryUIController>();
             InventoryUI.UpdateUI();
          }
          
          public void DeleteItem(){
            if(isSwapping == true){
              playerInventory.DeleteItem(tempIndex);
              isSwapping = false;
              InventoryUI.UpdateUI();
            }
          }
          
          public void DropItem(){
            if(isSwapping == true){
              playerInventory.DropItem(tempIndex,gameObject.transform.position+Vector3.forward);
              isSwapping = false;
              InventoryUI.UpdateUI();
            }
          }
        
          public void EatItem(){
            
          }
        
        
         //etc etc
```

Comment: What is an "item"? Presumably there's a class for each item in the game, that should be responsible for knowing whether it's consumable and what happens when it's consumed? If you made it implement some `IConsumable` interface you could implement this "Eat" (Consume?) method by calling the item's `Consume` method.

Comment: item is a just ScriptableObject all items have a prefab and icon in this inventory if we click the item icon and select the delete button item has gone and I want to make it like this but don't want to delete the item I want to give the player hunger++ in UI give some example we have a 90 hunger in-game and we select the item and eat it this hunger goes 100. It sounds simple when I describe it, but I get confused when I try to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in try this gameobject.getcompoment and its works

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Player>().hunger += 10f;
```

Comment: When you need another item that gives +20 instead of +10, you'll have to flip things around the way I commented about earlier, lest you end up with an inventory class with a huge switch block that knows about the specifics of every single item in the game. Best have that +10 on the item's side to begin with, and pass it the Player component, no? That said, if I eat an item, shouldn't my hunger stat be *decreasing*?

Comment: Also for performance reasons you'll probably want to retrieve the Player component on start (you already have a field for it!) rather than every time an item is eaten; GetComponent is an expensive call.